# Decompressing a .lzo file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, compression, lzo

Ok so i did a fair bit of search on the web and did not find any answers. I am writing a shell script wherein I need to decompress a .lzo file. Do not see any leads. Anyone has any idea? I am basically reading a timestamped log file. My scripts accepts the year, month, date as arguments. I am able to locate my file but now when I have to decompress it, I have no clue how to handle a .lzo file. Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention timestamps, compressed files, and a custom script but no code. Please include some [code](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) so we can see what it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: code that I used
`#!/bin/bash
path="/home/vviswanathan/NEAT/"
star="*"
dash="-"
if [ $1 -gt 0 -a $2 -gt 0 -a $3 -gt 0 ]
then
 cd $path
 if find $path -name "*$1-$2-$3*.lzo"
 then
  echo $path$star$1$dash$2$dash$3$star
  lzop -d "*neat*$1-$2-$3*.lzo"
  echo "return code was $?"
  echo "File exists"
 else
 echo "return code was $?"
 echo "File does not exists"
 fi
else
 echo "invalid input"
fi
exit 0

Comment: sorry about the format

Comment: Just edit your original question, and format it properly. Otherwise it's unreadable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Literally what I did to figure this out:

```
$ apropos lzo
IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress (3perl) - Uncompress gzip, zip, bzip2 or lzop file/buffer
```

Alright, so it's probably got something to do with `lzop`

```
$ lzo
No command 'lzo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lz' from package 'mtools' (main)
 Command 'lzop' from package 'lzop' (universe)
lzo: command not found
```

The last one looks like it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lzop
$ lzop 
[...]
Commands:
  -1     compress faster                   -9    compress better
  -d     decompress                        -x    extract (same as -dPp)
```

Aaand chocolate for everyone!

Comment: This has worked for me on a hadoop system but not in a shell script. Am I missing something?

Comment: What did you do, what did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: basically have a *.dat.lzo file. I have been using `lzop -d *dat..lzo` to decompress the file and operate on the .dat file obtained. But now I wish to write a script to perform the same action by just passing the yyyymmdd and get back the .dat file

Comment: Sorry guys. Had not installed lzop locally. One of those bad days I guess.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried using `lzop` with `-d` command?

```
lzop -d file.lzo
```

ref:  http://www.lzop.org/lzop_man.php

Regards.

Comment: This has worked for me on a hadoop system but not in a shell script. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vikas  what kind of error did you get?

Comment: lzop command not found

Comment: @Vikas try execute `which lzop` at you terminal to get the full path of lzop, then copy the full path into your script.